# Rolling Sum Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rolling-sum

If I have a dataframe and I want to use rolling sum to sum the previous n rows and the next n rows, what is the best way to do this?  I'm aware of the roll_sum, but I can't find a way to use it to fit my use case.  For example let's say I have the a vector n. And I specify that I want my window to be 1, that means for each record I want to sum it and the two adjacent records.

```
n   window1
1   NA
3   8
4   12
5   15
6   18
7   22
9   17
1   15
5   6
```

If I specified 2 as my window size then this would be the result:

```
n   window1 window2
1   NA  NA
3   8   NA
4   12  19
5   15  25
6   18  31
7   22  28
9   17  28
1   15  22
5   6   15
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: See the `RcppRoll` package; there you have the `roll_sum` function.

Comment: I see it, but I'm unsure of to get the desired output using it.

Comment: Related [Consecutive/Rolling sums in a vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200841/consecutive-rolling-sums-in-a-vector-in-r)

Comment: Or [Rolling sum in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403704/rolling-sum-in-dplyr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely dedicated functions, but this seems to work. It gives you some control on how you want it to behave. For example, the `default = 0` in the lead function allows it to go to the last record, even though there are no leading values. My bet is that this is relatively slow and inefficient.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

rolling_sum <- function(v, window = 1) {

  k <- 1:window

  vLag <- k %>%
    map_dfc(~lag(v, .))

  vLead <- k %>%
    map_dfc(~lead(v, ., default = 0))

  rowSums(bind_cols(vLag, V = v, vLead))

}

df <- data.frame(n = c(1,3,4,5,6,7,9,1,5))

df %>%
  mutate(window1 = rolling_sum(n, 1),
         window2 = rolling_sum(n, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think rollapplyr from the zoo package is your friend. With align = ‘center’ you can sum previous n rows and next n rows.